# In a Service Worker install listener, why does fetch return TypeError: Failed to fetch?

Tags: service-worker, sw-precache

Using the sw-precache utility, I created a service worker that works if I refresh the page. But initially, the fetch call returns `TypeError: Failed to fetch` on a file which seems to cancel the rest. Refresh gets a few more files, refresh a few more times until all are fetched and then the service worker works fine. Each url loads fine, every time, even with the cache buster. All the calls are to https://localhost:9001 and are straight `get` calls. There are 17 total files.

Here is a code snippet:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return setOfCachedUrls(cache).then(function(cachedUrls) {
        return Promise.all(
          Array.from(urlsToCacheKeys.values()).map(function(cacheKey) {
            // If we don't have a key matching url in the cache already, add it.
            if (!cachedUrls.has(cacheKey)) {
              var request = new Request(cacheKey, {credentials: 'same-origin'});
              return fetch(request).then(function(response) {
                // Bail out of installation unless we get back a 200 OK for
                // every request.
                if (!response.ok) {
                  throw new Error('Request for ' + cacheKey + ' returned a ' +
                    'response with status ' + response.status);
                }

                return cleanResponse(response).then(function(responseToCache) {
                  return cache.put(cacheKey, responseToCache);
                });
              }).catch(function(e) {
                  throw new Error('fetch error: ' + e);
              });
            }
          })
        );
      });
    }).then(function() {

    })
  );
});
```

I tried adding `keepalive:true,headers:{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}` to the Request but get the same result.

It seems the requests fail very soon, and I have seen the requests take a little more than a second to respond. Perhaps there is a way to set a timeout?

In the chrome dev tools network tab, it shows the failed attempts in red with a `(canceled)` status and the little service worker icon to the left.

It seems to work fine in FireFox. Chrome is having the trouble.

Comment: I assume https localhost is not supported. Why http localhost is ok for debugging but https localhost is not is beyond me!

Comment: Do you have a base href that is other than "<base href="/"/>"? I am having the same issue and can't find any information about base href influence to service workes

Comment: @MathiasS No, I am using that base href.